# Android Studio 3.2 not generating signed bundle/apk

Tags: android

I am using android studio 3.2, my machine has 8 GB ram and 2.2 GHZ core i7. However when creating a new key store the IDE freezes at the first step in the wizard. I have tried restarting my machine and android studio but the issue is persistence. Anyone who might have encountered this and what did you do. Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If nothing is happening after clicking on next, double-check your *key alias* if it matches the one you used when generating the *keystore*. I have had this kind of error when I was trying to use *key0* as an alias instead of *upload* which I had used before when generating *.jks*.

You can also check the *keystore password* and the *key password* if they match, but normally in this case, an error is thrown.

Comment: Remember Keystore password and key password cannot be the same. I was filling the same password for both.